# Is there any way to restrict creation of azure resources when a budget limit is crossed for a particular resource group

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I have set up a budget of 100$ for a particular azure resource group. I want a way to restrict creation of azure resources when the budget limit is reached. It seems like, we can achieve this by writing a custom policy. But I don't have a good knowledge of writing custom policies. So, please suggest me a way to achieve this goal, and provide a custom policy definition if any.

I have written the below custom policy to restrict creation of azure resources and it's working fine. But I also want to check the budget limit and current cost consumption amount, and the consumption is greater than or equals to budget limit.

```html
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "deny-resource-creation",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "All",
    "description": "Restrict creation of azure resources.",
    "metadata": {
      "createdBy": "62eddff1-******",
      "createdOn": "2023-05-26T05:08:07.5646255Z",
      "updatedBy": null,
      "updatedOn": null
    },
    "parameters": {},
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "like": "Microsoft.*"
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "deny"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to restrict creation of azure resources when a budget limit is crossed for a particular resource group.

If you apply the below policy, it will deny the Resource creation when the budget amount is greater than or equal to the value specified in the `budgetAmount` parameter.
( $100). and it will deny resource creation for budgets (`Microsoft.Consumption/budgets`) associated with the specified resource group.

**Here is the updated Policy:**

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Consumption/budgets"
        },
        {
          "field": "name",
          "equals": "[concat(parameters('resourceGroupName'), '-Budget')]"
        },
        {
          "field": "type",
          "greaterOrEquals": "[parameters('budgetAmount')]"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "budgetAmount": {
      "type": "Integer",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "budgetAmount",
        "description": "The maximum budget amount."
      },
      "defaultValue": 100
    },
    "resourceGroupName": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "resourceGroupName",
        "description": "The name of the resource group to apply the policy to."
      },
      "defaultValue": "ResourceGroup-Name"
    }
  }
}
```

Assign the `Azure Policy` as below.

[image]

Disclaimer : I don’t have `Enterprise Agreement Account` to create a budget for the `resource group` to validate the policy, However, the policy I created does not have any code errors. If you have already created the budget in your environment, you can test the same policy for restricting the resource creation.

Comment: Thanks @Venkat.
What I understood from the above policy is that if I give a value of 100$ in the budgetAmount (in parameter while assigning the policy), one can't create a budget of more than 100$ on that scope. Hope you will consider my apologies if I misunderstood. 
My actual requirement is to restrict creation of azure resources like compute, networking, storage etc. once the actual cost consumption crosses the budget limit. If you can provide a custom policy or any other solution, that will be really helpful.
Disclaimer: I have already setup the budget.